How to remove existing user assigned managed identity from redis cache using c# and .net
ManagedServiceIdentity managedIdentity = 
new ManagedServiceIdentity(ManagedServiceIdentityType.UserAssigned);
 managedIdentity.UserAssignedIdentities.Add(
     userIdentity.Id, null);

RedisPatch patch = new RedisPatch()
{
   Identity = managedIdentity
};


RedisResource resource = redisCollection.GetAsync(clusterName).GetResult();

resource.UpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, patch).GetResult();

I m switching back from managed identity to connection string based authentcation for redis cache. But I couldnt remove the exisiting user assigned managed identity from the cache
Error

ERROR: Content:
ERROR: {"error":{"code":"FailedIdentityOperation","message":"Identity operation for resource '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Cache/Redis/xxx' failed with error 'Failed to perform resource identity operation. 
Status: 'BadRequest'. 
Response: '{\"error\":{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":
\"Removal of all user-assigned identities assigned to resource '/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/TEstRGSandBox1/providers/Microsoft.Cache/Redis/xxx' 
with type 'UserAssigned' is invalid.\"}}'.'."}}
  


You can use Azure Rest API Redis to update the managed Identity type:-
Rest API Document:-
PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Cache/redis/{cacheName}?api-version=2023-08-01
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <your_access_token>

{
  "properties": {
    "enableNonSslPort": true,
    "replicasPerPrimary": 2,
    "identity": {
      "type": "SystemAssigned"
    }
  }
}

C# code:-
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Redis;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Redis.Models;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);
        string subscriptionId = "bxxxxxxxxx2xxxxf";
        string resourceGroupName = "rg-name";
        string name = "siliconredis";
        ResourceIdentifier redisResourceId = RedisResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, name);
        RedisResource redis = client.GetRedisResource(redisResourceId);

  
        RedisPatch patch = new RedisPatch()
        {
            Identity = null 
        };

        ArmOperation<RedisResource> lro = await redis.UpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, patch);
        RedisResource result = lro.Value;

        RedisData resourceData = result.Data;

        Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded on id: {resourceData.Id}");
    }
}

Output:-

Reference source code.

identity = null, didnt remove the managed identity. It didnt make any change
@SiddheshDesai
